# QTableWidget not updating when called outside of class

Tags: python, pyqt5

EDIT:
Placing this in my MainWindow class fixed the issue.

```
def changeEvent(self, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ActivationChange:
        self.defaultData()
```

I am attempting to teach myself SQL by creating a simple CRUD database. My MainWindow class populates my table properly on initialization of the program using the code below:(see below)
[Program Initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg9l5.jpg)

```
def defaultData(self):
    include.tableRow = 0
    include.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product")
    fetch = include.cursor.fetchall()
    include.tableCount = self.tableCounter(fetch)
    self.tableView.setRowCount(include.tableCount)
    if fetch is None:
        return
    for row in fetch:
        for i in range(10):
            self.tableView.setItem(include.tableRow, int(i), QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[int(i)])))
        include.tableRow += 1
```

The problem I am facing; however, is that I have a separate class for an AddWindow, which calls MainWindow().defaultData(). I can see that the function is being executed and my fetch command is grabbing the new addition; however, new rows aren't being updated (see below)[Item Added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEpbw.jpg)

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_addButton_clicked(self):
    a = self.quantityInput.text()
    b = self.descriptionInput.text()
    c = self.numberInput.text()
    d = self.serialInput.text()
    e = self.cabinetInput.text()
    f = self.rowInput.text()
    g = self.shelfInput.text()
    h = self.slotInput.text()
    i = self.binInput.text()
    self.on_resetButton_clicked()
    self.sendMessage("Item Added!")
    database.addItem(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
    MainWindow().defaultData()
```

I can get the data to reload by calling defaultData() from within the MainWindow() class. [Table View After Reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu72S.jpg)

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def on_action_Reset_triggered(self):
    self.defaultData()
```

Can someone help me understand why self.defaultData() behaves differently than MainWindow().defaultData()?